# use lodash to find substring from array and to push them to another and then to compare result with the 3rd table

Tags: javascript, testing, lodash, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have array:

```
all [a,b,ac,d, A]
```

and I want to find in this all elements which include substring "a" ("A") using filter from lodash and push them to another - to the filterTab

```
   const item = "a"
```

I try sth like this:

```
import { some, method, differenceWith, isEquel } from 'lodash';
const filterTab = [];

filterTab.push (some(all, method('match',/item/i)));
```

But it does not work.

The next step if it works- it will be something like this:

```
var dif = differenceWith(filterTab, array3, _.isEqual);
```

And I have no idea why it does not work...

Comment: What's a "*table*"? What do you mean by "*3rd*"? What is "*`filterTab`*"? Do you have to use lodash? What about just the JavaScript [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)?

Comment: try breaking your solution. trying doing everything heck i even don't do it from 10 year "filterTab.push (some(all, method('match',/item/i)));" don't do this. trying breaking your solution and then put it back together

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to put every value that matches `item` from `all` into `filterTab` and then get the difference between `filterTab` and `array3`, use this example:

```js
import { filter, difference, method } from 'lodash';

const all = ['a','b','ac','d', 'A'];

const filterTab = [];
const item = 'a';

filterTab.push(...filter(all, method('match', new RegExp(item, 'i'))));

const diff = difference(array3, filterTab);
```